# Convert Java Project to .Exe

Tags: java, netbeans, executable

I've created a game project in NetBeans 6.9, and I want to run the project on another computer. The problem is if NetBeans is not installed on the other computer then surely I cannot run the project.
Therefore I have to convert my project into a .exe that can be run on other computers without having to install NetBeans.

Is there a free application that can convert .java to .exe?
Please help me to convert my project into a .exe file. Thanks.

Comment: You have to install Java on the other computer. Then, copy the contents of the dist folder to that computer. After that, open the dist folder on the other computer and double click on the jar file. Nice and simple.

Answer (score 3):

Check out these official netbeans article for [Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) and [Developing General Java Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-intro.html).

From the article

#### Running the Application Inside of the IDE

When developing applications in the IDE, typically you will need to test and refine them before distributing them. You can easily test an application that you are working on by running the application from the IDE.

To run the AnotherGrep project in the IDE, right-clicking the project's node (AnotherGrep) in the Projects window and choose Run Project.

The xGrep window should open. You can click the Browse button to choose a file in which to search for a text pattern. In the Search Pattern field, type text or a regular expression pattern that you would like to match, and click Search. The results of each match will appear in the xGrep window's Output area.

Information on regular expressions that you can use in this application are available here and in many other places on the World Wide Web.

#### Running the Application Outside of the IDE

Once you have finished developing the application and before you distribute it, you will probably want to make sure that the application also works outside of the IDE.

You can run the application outside of the IDE by following these steps:

**In your system's file manager (for example, in the My Computer window on Windows XP systems), navigate to PROJECT_HOME/dist and double-click the AnotherGrep.jar file.**

You will know that the application has started successfully when the xGrep window opens.

If the xGrep window does not open, your system probably does not have a file association between JAR files and the Java Runtime Environment. See [Troubleshooting JAR File Associations](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting).

#### Distributing the Application to Other Users

Now that you have verified that the application works outside of the IDE, you are ready to distribute it.
You can distribute the application by following these steps:

**1:** Create a zip file that contains the application JAR file (`AnotherGrep.jar`) and the accompanying `lib folder` that contains `swing-layout-1.0.jar`.

**2:** Send the file to the people who will use the application. Instruct them to unpack the zip file, making sure that the `AnotherGrep.jar` file and the `lib folder` are in the same folder.

The users of your application should be able to run it by double-clicking the JAR file. If this does not work for them, show them the information in the [Troubleshooting JAR File Associations section](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting).

Also some third party tools like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) may do the trick. For more information see this article on [java-to-exe](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html)

Answer (score 2):

See [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).  I dislike starting java apps with a batch file.  This wraps anything from the root jar all the way up to a complete Java environment in an exe. You get your own icon in the system tray rather than the generic coffee cup.  I've used it successfully on a project that has about 300,000 downloads, and it's never been the source of a reported bug.  NB It does take some careful reading to pick the right options for your project.  But you can set it up with the Ant build script in Netbeans to make the .exe automatically.  Very nice and clean.  My project includes native libraries. They work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) will help you . Most of the applications using NSIS. Because it is open source.

Also there is a Eclipse plugin for NSIS to make the process easy.

http://hmne.sourceforge.net/